# How to pass state into component when rendering in storybook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

The component that I am trying to test uses the useSelector hook to assign data to a variable.

When I render the component in storybook, the useSelector returns undefined. What is the proper way to retrieve the data in storybook in situations like this?

I have it wrapped in Provider tags that take in the store but I need the state.

Comment: can you provide the code snippets in codesandbox ?